# native component under cordova webview

Tags: android, cordova

I try to use a native android map control in an cordova based application. For this reason I try to put the native map view under the transparent cordovaWebView.

Now, is there any chance to detect if the user touched on the transparent area of the cordovaWebView or on any html element rendered on the cordovaWebView.

I somehow need the position of the div elements on the webView. Is there any other chance to retrieve them from the native android part of my application ? I really don't want to pass them during the initialisation of the map (like the cordova-maps-plugin is doing it).

I hope it's clear what I want to achieve.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the JS map api?

Comment: That would be too easy ;) It's just a show case of what we can do or what is possible and what not. Just a kind of proof of concept.